# Windows 7 "Search" broken

Tags: windows-7, search

For some reason, my Search field in the Start Menu has disappeared. When I press <kbd>F3</kbd> (which should bring up Search) I get the following error message:

> search:
>
> Class not registered

Any idea?

Edit: Running Windows 7 RTM and Windows Search is checked in "Windows Features".

Now the error has changed:

> search-ms:crumb=location:[path to
>   'desktop']
>
> Class not registered

Comment: How did you do that? Can you check System Restore and see if anything changed? Also try **Control Panel\System and Security\Action Center\Reliability Monitor** and see if anything crashed.

Comment: What version are you running? Beta, RTM, Released version?

Comment: RTM ... and hell if i know what caused it. i'm kinda baffled here, everything looks hunky-dory.

Comment: Well, that makes 2 of us who are baffled...

Comment: 3 of us. Sounds like something became corrupt. If a restore/repair doesn't do it, sounds like a reinstall is in order :(

Answer (score 1):

I'd begin by running a `chkdsk /r` and then a `sfc /scannow` from the Command Prompt.

If your problem is being caused by a corrupt or borked Windows file / setting, that *should* go a long way in fixing the issue.

Also, are there any entries in Event Viewer?

Comment: this was a fresh installation and i'm running out of time here, so i just reinstall the whole lot now.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, I think that's the answer:

1. Right-click on the Start button
2. Click on Properties
3. Select the Start Menu tab
4. Press the Customize button
5. Select the Advanced tab
6. Scroll down through the Start menu items list
7. Check the box next to Search and Run
8. Press OK twice

If that doesn't work because the item was already checked, then UNcheck it, press OK, go back in and then REcheck it.

[image]

Comment: i did try that ... to no avail. there was something sinister going on :) anyway, reinstallation did the trick. as it does so often. really like to have more time to investigate when something like this happens, especially with a new OS, but unfortunately that's not what i'm getting paid for.

Comment: So a mystery it will stay.

Comment: I hope that machine doesn't have a hardware problem, to develop such a weirdo.

Answer (score 1):

Just go into Control Panel->Programs and Features->Turn Windows Features on/off

There should be an item called 'Windows Search'... Check it and save.

Answer (score 0):

This error is when starting Windows 7 in safe mode. And later SEARCH FIELD and "Option Folder" disappeared.

RE.
Option Folder is the easy solution, but for the search field my solution for the moment is to reinstall Windows 7.

Comment: that's exatcly what i did ... reinstalling, i mean :)